# Old safari on Yosemite

Tags: macos, safari

Is it possible to get Safari 5.1 running on Yosemite next to Safari 8?

(For testing web pages)

Comment: It would be easier to use Windows, as that was the last version made for Windows, so it won't have to fight against v8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can install an older version of OS X in a virtual machine to use Safari there.

Comment: ok I hoped it would be an easier way. Do you know which Mac OS  has Safari 5 and which vm host is the best for running Mac OS ?

Comment: Snow Leopard runs Safari 5. I use Parallels Desktop for VMs but VirtualBox is a good alternative.

Comment: quick Google shows 5.1.10 as Snow Leopard OS X 10.6.8 - http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1569?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US